# Using grep and awk together

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file (A.txt) with 4 columns of numbers and another file with 3 columns of numbers (B.txt). I need to solve the following problems:

1. Find all lines in A.txt whose 3rd column has a number that appears any where in the 3rd column of B.txt.
2. Assume that I have many files like A.txt in a directory and I need to run this for every file in that directory.

How do I do this?

Comment: A `while` loop together with `awk` should suffice. What have you tried? Do you have any sample input together with desired output?

Comment: pls paste some example... sounds like awk can handle it.

Comment: @fedorqui, shouldn't even need a while loop

Comment: This (1) sounds like a good job for `join`... along with a `for` loop to iterate through the individual files (2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example. Create the following files and run

```
awk -f c.awk B.txt A*.txt
```

**c.awk**

```
FNR==NR {
    s[$3]
    next
}

$3 in s {
    print FILENAME, $0
}
```

**A1.txt**

```
1 2 3
1 2 6
1 2 5
```

**A2.txt**

```
1 2 3
1 2 6
1 2 5
```

**B.txt**

```
1 2 3
1 2 5
2 1 8
```

The output should be:

```
A1.txt 1 2 3
A1.txt 1 2 5
A2.txt 1 2 3
A2.txt 1 2 5
```

Comment: Tha'ts pretty good. However, what happens if there's a line in `B.txt` that is not in the other files?

Comment: I added this line to **B.txt** '2 1 8'. It does not change the output.

Comment: Okay, I see. The FNR is only for the ORIGINAL file. You're only putting stuff in `s` if the line is in `B.txt`. I take it the second half is only executed once you're out of `B.txt`.

Answer (score 40):

You should never see someone using `grep` and `awk` together because whatever `grep` can do, you can also do in `awk`:

#### Grep and Awk

```
grep "foo" file.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

#### Using Only Awk:

```
awk '/foo/ {print $1}' file.txt
```

I had to get that off my chest. Now to your problem...

Awk is a programming language that assumes a single loop through all the lines in a set of files. And, you don't want to do this. Instead, you want to treat `B.txt` as a special file and loop though your other files. That normally calls for something like Python or Perl. (Older versions of BASH didn't handle hashed key arrays, so these versions of BASH won't work.) However, [slitvinov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865811/368630) looks like he found an answer.

Here's a Perl solution anyway:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

my $b_file = shift;
open my $b_fh, "<", $b_file;

#
# This tracks the values in "B"
#
my %valid_lines;
while ( my $line = <$b_file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
    $valid_lines{$array[2]} = 1;   #Third column
}
close $b_file;

#
# This handles the rest of the files
#
while ( my $line = <> ) {  # The rest of the files
   chomp $line;
   my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
   next unless exists $valid_lines{$array[2]};  # Next unless field #3 was in b.txt too
   say $line;
}
```

Comment: Re: `You should never see someone using grep and awk together...` I've got a series of `syslog` files in `/var/log` (some compressed). I need to match against a string `voltage` as a flag that further processing is required, but this string isn't always in the same field. `zgrep` and `awk` strike me as a reasonable approach for this. If I can accomplish a complex `awk` action with a simple `grep` action, then why not ?