# awk to match pattern from a file to another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

To find a string in a file and print first column of the output, we can use

`grep "foo" file.txt | awk '{print $1}'` which can be done using `awk` alone

`awk '/foo/ {print $1}' file.txt` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866418/1662898).

Instead of a single string (foo) as a pattern, I want to search for a list of strings in a file. Using `grep`, it would be

```
grep -f file.txt file2.txt | awk '{print $1}' > outFile.txt
```

Can I do the same using `awk` alone?

```
file.txt
abcd
acde
a2rt

file2.txt
1 albcd dhakd kdf
3 abcdbd and
2a bda2rt tert

outFile.txt
3
2a
```

Thanks!
Abhishek

Comment: which columns you want to compare from file.txt and file2.txt please be clear in information, so that we could try to help you.

Comment: file.txt contains one string (pattern) per line and anywhere in file2.txt (no specific column.

Comment: `grep -f`  the `-F` is redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalent `awk` command will be this one:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for (i in a) if (index($0, i)) print $1}' file.txt file1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
3
2a
```

Using non-regex string comparison `(index($0, i))` instead of a regex match `($0 ~ i)` because of `-F` option of `grep`.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is going on here?

Comment: In the first pass we build an array with 1st column of `file.txt`. In second pass we loop through array and check if array entry is a substring of full line from 2nd file

Comment: WARNING: this doesn't work for regexps.
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

index(in, find)
Search the string in for the first occurrence of the string find, and return the position in characters where that occurrence begins in the string in.

`$ awk 'BEGIN { print index("peanut", "an") }'  ==>  
-| 3`
If find is not found, index() returns zero.

With BWK awk and gawk, it is a fatal error to use a regexp constant for find. Other implementations allow it, simply treating the regexp constant as an expression meaning ‘$0 ~ /regexp/’. (d.c.)

Comment: Sorry didn't really understand context of regex here.